Ubuntu 24.04, app file mangers cant locate second drive
On update from 22.04 to 24.04, the file managers in the apps are not right and cannot locate my data drive and in general the do not have the same appearance as before. This is not a drive issue, Nautilus recognizes the drive, Disks sees the drive text editor sees the drive. LibreOffec and Onlyoffice don not and the window that opens when clicking on files/open is different. How do I fix this so my files can be accesed?   I can got to nautilus and launch the file and app from there but that cumbersome.
